# Change values of panda.dataframe (fast way) in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform an operation on a specific column of a pandas.dataframe.

From this:

```
# admit gre gpa rank
# 0 0 1123 3.61 3
# 1 1 4454 3.67 3
# 2 1 8000 4.00 1
# 3 1 6405 3.19 4
# 4 0 5205 2.93 4
```

I want to change the gre column this way: Select just the last two numbers.. (ex: df['gre':0] = 1123 => 23).
I have a very big set of data so, I am looking for a simple way to do so without running through the pandas data frame, I tried the python for loop:

```
for i in df.index:
   df.loc[i, 'gre'] = str(df.loc[i, 'gre'])[2:3]
```

This work but it take time.. A lot of it.. Thanks

Comment: Is the dtype already a string or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dtype is numeric then you can convert to a string and then take the last 2 characters:

```
In [4]:

df['gre'] = df['gre'].astype(str).str[-2:]
df
Out[4]:
   admit gre   gpa  rank
0      0  23  3.61     3
1      1  54  3.67     3
2      1  00  4.00     1
3      1  05  3.19     4
4      0  05  2.93     4
```

If it's already a string then `df['gre'] = df['gre'].str[-2:]` would work fine.

You can then convert back:

```
In [7]:

df['gre'] = df['gre'].astype(np.int64)
df.dtypes
Out[7]:
admit      int64
gre        int64
gpa      float64
rank       int64
dtype: object
```

**timings**

```
In [9]:

%%timeit 
for i in df.index:
   df.loc[i, 'gre'] = str(df.loc[i, 'gre'])[2:3]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.98 ms per loop
In [11]:

%timeit df['gre'] = df['gre'].astype(str).str[-2:]

1000 loops, best of 3: 380 µs per loop
```

We can see that using the vectorised `str` method is over 700X faster

Comment: How to do it? I am sorry I am relatively new here :/

Comment: There will be a tick mark underneath the down arrow next to the answer, at the top left

Comment: I need to wait  minute at least :p